# lappend adds curly braces to the element

Tags: tcl

I am using `lappend` in script, doing something like this:

```
set element_name a[0]  
lappend mylist $element_name
```

I see that if the `$element_name` contains a `[]` in it for e.g. `a[0]`. The `lappend` adds curly braces to it. Like if I print `$mylist` then it gives:

```
{a[0]}
```

How do i get rid of those curly braces? I just want `a[0]`.

Comment: That first line should generate an error, `invalid command name 0`, unless you wrote it as `{a[0]}` or `"a\[0\]"`

Comment: @slebetman: `a\[0]` without double quotes is sufficient.

Comment: Or you have a command: `proc 0 {} {return {[0]}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The braces disappear if you use `join` to convert the list to a string:

```
puts [join $mylist]
# => a[0]
```

or if you print the elements separately:

```
foreach elem $mylist {puts $elem}
```

The string representation of a list needs to quote elements that contain characters that are significant to the interpreter and/or interfere with the list structure. Brackets (with a script in between them) are usually interpreted as a command substitution, and to prevent the interpreter from evaluating that, your elements are wrapped in braces. Once the list elements are converted to a string, this ceases to be an issue, and the text you stored in them is no longer wrapped up.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm)